# RISC-V floating-point rounding results Spike Vs. RTL simulation

Tags: floating-point, riscv

I am running a program with float and double instructions and I am observing mismatches in write-back values of these instructions when comparing my RTL simulation and Spike.

For example:

```
fsqrt.d fa3, fa3 
Instruction in hex: 0x5a06c6d3
```

Value of the input argument to the instruction is

```
0x41e2e80040000000 = 2537554432.0
sqrt(2537554432.0) = 50374.1444790876820703394273903...
```

According to the RISC-V spec and the decoded instruction, rounding mode of this instruction is **Round to Nearest, ties to Max Magnitude (RMM)**.
I am getting the following write-back values from Spike and RTL sim.

```
Spike   = 0x40e898c49f929b92 (in hex) = 50374.144479087685 (in decimal)
RTL sim = 0x40e898c49f929b91 (in hex) = 50374.144479087680 (in decimal)
```

Looking at the actual decimal value, it seems like RTL result is closer to the actual value and therefore giving the correct result, but both Spike and dromajo give the same value which is slightly different.

**I wanted to confirm which result is correct and whether this kind of mismatch can be considered a buggy behavior in floating-point arithmetic.**

Please let me know any information that willhelp to resolve my doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems like RTL result is closer to the actual value

No, Spike is closer.  Your observation is askew due to [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) and inferior OP's RTL sim `double` to text.  Use better library and more decimal precision to see.

```
Spike (OP)   = 0x40e898c49f929b92     50374.144479087 685 (in decimal)
Spike        =  0x1.898c49f929b92p+15 50374.144479087 684886               +0028
sqrt(2537554432.0)                    50374.144479087 6820703394273903...
RTL sim      =  0x1.898c49f929b91p+15 50374.144479087 677610               -0044
RTL sim (OP) = 0x40e898c49f929b91     50374.144479087 680 (in decimal)
```

---

I suspect the error in `RTL sim` with `50374.144479087680` might be due to its library `double` to text code running incorrectly while in *Round to Nearest, ties to Max Magnitude (RMM)*.